# How to convert a molecular structure made in Avogadro to a LAMMPS coordinate file?

Tags: software, lammps, avogadro

I was trying to convert a crystal structure into a LAMMPS data file in Avogadro but whenever I type .lmpdat as an extension, it says "The file name is not valid". Can you tell me any solution?

i.e. I have also tried .lmp extension

I have been following this tutorial:
https://avogadro.cc/docs/extensions/lammps-input-for-water/

Comment: While I can't provide help with Avogadro, I wanted to let you know that this can also be done using [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/io/io.html).

Comment: +1. Welcome to our site! We hope to see much more of you here!! As for your problem, I think you might have to be more specific about what exactly you did. I looked at the link you provided and I guess it's the section "Generate the LAMMPS parameters file" that caused a problem for you, at step 3 of that section. The screenshot on that site says .lmp but your question says that you typed .lmpdat. Have you tried just .lmp? If you could be a bit more specific and maybe show screenshots of what you did, it might be helpful. Hopefully we get your problem solved quickly!

Comment: I had no issue getting this to work for methane or silver. Assuming you did a normal install of Avogadro, it should have OpenBabel installed as well, which is what actually does the conversion. At the moment, we don't have enough information to address your question.

Comment: You don't mention what version of Avogadro you're using, but I'd recommend posting at https://discuss.avogadro.cc - although suffice to say that a new script is probably more useful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the post has been abandoned by the user, who has not signed in since 1 day after asking the question; and Tyberius says that more details are required; and perhaps someone familiar with the Avogadro forum can see whether or not the user followed Geoff's advice to ask the question there.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your suggestions. I have not installed open babel. I am looking into it.

Comment: @AbdullahArafat great! We can re-open the question once you've tried the above questions, or if someone comments saying that they want to answer.

Comment: @AbdullahArafat I see your re-open vote, but all you added was "I have also tried .lmp extension". Tyberius said that "we don't have enough information to address your question", and I know nothing about this area of modeling, so I'll have to wait to see if Tyberius thinks that having tried the .lmp extension, there is now enough information.

Comment: I am using ovito for conversion now. So I don't need it. And also the answer from Andrew Rosen helped me. Thanks everyone for the cooperation.

Comment: Just a recap: This was closed because the user doesn't need an answer anymore since they're using OVITO to accomplish the task, and Andrew's suggestion of using ASE helped. The question was about getting it done in Avogadro, but Geoff pointed out that the version # of Avogadro was not given.